# Book about a warrior who leaves his family to go on a journey to fight dark forces

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about 10 years ago, it is about a warrior who leaves his family to go on a journey to fight dark forces I think.

He crosses a desert with evil nomads. There's also a druid in the books with a king eagle he can share sight with. The son of the warrior sees the king eagle's forbidden secret ritual at some point and his sight gets replaced with shared sight of the king eagle, or was it a raven? I also believe the evil forces came from across the sea/ ocean.

There was an evil main character called the indoctrinator I think. Also a child is born that leads the evil forces and I believe it's called something like messianas? I think one of the covers had an image of a Rocky coast with a warrior on one of the bigger rocks but I could be wrong.